# Cross Platform Application Deployment Tool

Tags: web-applications, mobile, deployment, sencha-touch

I have developed a mobile application with Sencha Touch which is currently working on iOS and Android devices. It also works on Chrome and Safari and it's Chrome packaged app as well and accessible form Chrome Web Store. It has PHP parts which is application's backbone. Because source code is open source you can take a look yourself the whole structure at github https://github.com/umrashrf/IQRA-University-Smartphone-App.

Now everything is cool except deploying this application is a pain. Whenever I change anything in **/sencha** folder, I have to update **/android**, **/ios**, and **ftp** chnaged stuff. Note that I just don't replace those folders with **/sencha** folder but some files need to be modified too. For example, to ftp stuff for web, I have to make sure /sencha/index.html don't have **cordova.js** in there but android and iOS version do. Also because **BaseURL** in **/sencha/app.js** is relative URL in development mode, I have to change it to absolute internet URL for android and iOS production builds.

Is there a deployment tool which I can tell what files to send to **/android**, **/iOS** and **ftp**? And also specify somehow that change some files for different production builds?

**UPDATED**

Also when I build for android and iOS, I have to increment their version code to deploy.

I am looking for one click deployment tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, it sounds like you're describing the **Patched Application Pattern**, wherein you have a single codebase that ends up being transformed into multiple, distinct applications by applying a patch before or after compilation.

This pattern is pretty common in "quasi-custom" software, wherein there's a "product" that is customized for each customer. The core codebase is shared, and each customer has their own tweaks (whether it's a logo file, a runtime discovered file, a change in a .cs file, etc) that are applied either before or after the build step.

I see this pattern implemented quite a bit with [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com) using a couple different techniques. Either multiple deployables in one application (if they are always deployed at same time), or by using "imported deployable" (if each instance can be deployed at differnt times).